# how to know if range slider change is made by client or by modifying its value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, slider, range, rangeslider

Is there any way to know if range slider change is made by client or by modifying its value with javascript?

```js
var caller = "by the client";

document.getElementById('mySlider').oninput = function() {
console.log("Changed "+caller+" to "+this.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="mySlider" type="range" value="50" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: Well, I am not sure if I have understood the question. What do you mean by `modifying its value with javascript`? Won't you be writing the code for doing this? And, if it so, you can always keep track of it

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) which specifies whether an event was created by user interaction (`true`) or via something like JavaScript manipulation (`false`):

```
var caller = "by the client";

document.getElementById('mySlider').oninput = function(event) {
  if (event.isTrusted) {
    /* The event is trusted, generated by a user action */
  } else {
    /* The event is not trusted, generated or modified by a script or dispatched via EventTarget.dispatchEvent()  */
  }
}
```

```js
var inputEl = document.getElementById('foo');

inputEl.onchange = function (event) {
  console.log(event.isTrusted);
}

document.getElementById('bar').onclick = function() {
  inputEl.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="foo" name="foo" />

<button type="button" id="bar">change value</button>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: its good, thank you, but it doesn't really solve my issue, you see I wanna know if the value is change without simulating any event

Comment: @wooldLucky your question may not be clear then. Is the issue that the change event doesn’t trigger under specific conditions and therefore you can detect if a change occurred?

Comment: the issue is a little bit weird, on chrome my slider works just fine, but on firefox, the last value recorded before the page unloads keep being calling back whenever I change the range's value and also when the page loads, I have tried event.isTrusted and seems like the event is trusted some for the moment nothinga has worked